# ¿Cómo puedo pasar varios parámetros a una función en php?

Tags: php, php7, php5

Estoy intentando pasar parámetros a una función para luego generar una url, he creado una función pero no me funciono por algo que estoy haciendo mal.

```
function url($array){

    $url = 'dominio.com/casas/';

    if ($array) {
        $url .= '?filter&';
    }

    if ($array['cuidad']) {
        $url .= 'cuidad='.$array['cuidad'];
    }

    if ($array['zona']) {
        $url .= 'zona='.$array['zona'];
    }

    if ($array['tipo']) {
        $url .= 'tipo='.$array['tipo'];
    }

    return $url;

}
```

Ejemplo del resultado que quiero obtener.

Si por ejemplo quiero obtener todas las casas de una cuidad sin la zona ni el tipo seria pasar el parametro asi:

```
<?php echo url('cuidad', $valor); ?>
```

y si quiero obtener por cuidad y tipo seria algo asi:

```
<?php echo url('cuidad', $valor, 'tipo', $valor); ?>
```

El problema que tengo es como convertir esos parametros en array asociativo para cada valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar un arreglo utilizando tu código seria así

`<?php echo url(['cuidad' => $valor, 'tipo' => $valor2]); ?>`

> Ten en cuenta que dice **cuidad** y no *ciudad*

Adicionalmente hago un ajuste en tu función url

Para la validación utilice [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

> Isset: Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL.

```
function url($array){

    $url = 'dominio.com/casas';  //Acá quite el / luego de casas

    if (isset($array)) {
        $url .= '?filter';       //Acá quite el & luego de filter
    }

    if (isset($array['cuidad'])) {
        $url .= '&cuidad='.$array['cuidad'];   //Acá agregue el & antes de cuidad
    }

    if (isset($array['zona'])) {
        $url .= '&zona='.$array['zona'];       //Acá agregue el & antes de zona
    }

    if (isset($array['tipo'])) {
        $url .= '&tipo='.$array['tipo'];      //Acá agregue el & antes de tipo
    }

    return $url;

}
```

Ejemplos:
`<?php echo url(['cuidad' => 'alpha', 'zona' => 'beta']); ?>`
*Mostraría:* dominio.com/casas?filter&cuidad=alpha&zona=beta

`<?php echo url(null); ?>`
*Mostraría:* dominio.com/casas

---

Modificando función para recibir 3 parámetros y forma de usar

```
function url($ciudad = null, $zona = null, $tipo = null){

    $url = 'dominio.com/casas';

    if ($ciudad != null || $zona != null || $tipo != null) {
        $url .= '?filter';
    }

    if ($ciudad != null) {
        $url .= '&cuidad='.$ciudad;
    }

    if ($zona != null) {
        $url .= '&zona='.$zona;
    }

    if ($tipo != null) {
        $url .= '&tipo='.$tipo;
    }

    return $url;

}
```

Ejemplos:
`<?php echo url('alpha', null, 'un_tipo'); ?>`
*Mostraría:* dominio.com/casas?filter&cuidad=alpha&tipo=un_tipo

`<?php echo url(); ?>`
*Mostraría:* dominio.com/casas

Comment: Me funciono muchas gracias, pero la idea que tenia yo era sin pasar el nombre del parametro ciudad, zona o tipo, eso seria posible respetando el orden de los parametros?

Comment: Agregue la otra forma que solicitas para pasar los parámetros

Comment: si eso ya lo he intentado pero funciona si se mantiene el orden de los parámetros, por ejemplo si quiero las casas por tipo y la función es url($ciudad = null, $zona = null, $tipo = null) y hago un echo url('apartamentos') devolvería la url como casas/cuidad=apartamento a no ser que haya otro método de hacerlo que yo no lo sepa

Comment: la funcion 2 es exactamente lo que hice y lo que quiero evitar es eso de poner null en el echo.